# How to print the HasMap key and value data in separate text fields?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I am using Struts2 tags in JSP. Below is the `Action` class.

```
package com.action;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
public class EmpLeavePlan extends ActionSupport{
private String bankId;
private String empName;
private String monthYear;
private String leaves;
private Map<String,String> bankIds;
public String display() {
    return "SUCESS";
}
public String getDefaultSearchEngine() {
    return "yahoo.com";
}
public String execute() throws Exception
{
    bankIds = new HashMap<String,String>();
    bankIds.put("1541742","h6");
    bankIds.put("1541742","eft");
    bankIds.put("1394842","dfd");
    bankIds.put("1541742","dfee");
        return "SUCCESS";}
public String getBankId() {
    return bankId;
}
public Map<String, String> getBankIds() {
    return bankIds;
}
public void setBankIds(Map<String, String> bankIds) {
    this.bankIds = bankIds;
}
public void setBankId(String bankId) {
    this.bankId = bankId;
}
public String getEmpName() {
    return empName;
}
public void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.empName = empName;
}
public String getMonthYear() {
    return monthYear;
}
public void setMonthYear(String monthYear) {
    this.monthYear = monthYear;
}
public String getLeaves() {
    return leaves;
}
public void setLeaves(String leaves) {
    this.leaves = leaves;
}}
```

**JSP:**

```jsp
  <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
      var currentDate = new Date();
      $("#datepicker").datepicker( {
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          showButtonPanel: true,
          dateFormat: 'MM yy'
          /* onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
              $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
          } */
          
      });
      $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
      
      
  });
  
   </script>
  
  <style>
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
   
    }
    .ui-datepicker-year{
  
    width: 70px !important;
    height: 25px;
     }
    .ui-datepicker-month{
     width: 60px !important;
    height: 25px;
    }
    .ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all{
    width: 213px !important;
    }
</style>
<h1> Leave Plan Management!!! </h1>
<body style="background-color:lightgrey;">
<s:form action="bankgen">
<s:textfield name="monthYear" label="Month/Year" id="datepicker"></s:textfield>
<%-- <s:select label="Select Bank ID" 
        headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select bank id"  list="bankIds" 
        name="bankIdd" id="bankChange" /> --%>
<s:select label="Select Bank ID" 
        headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select bank id"  list="bankIds"  
        name="bankId" id="bankChange" />    
        
<s:textfield name="empName" label="Name" id="empName"></s:textfield>
<s:textarea name="leaves" label="Leaves :" id="leaves"></s:textarea>
<s:submit value="save"></s:submit>

</s:form>
</body>
```

However, I am not getting the output. In the dropdown the values alone are reflection and not the key which is the `bank id`. I want the bank ids to be in the `bank id` column and the key values to be in the `emp` name column.

Comment: Im initiating the url with "http://localhost:8080/Demostruts/selectAction.action" instead of directly calling the jsp. I need the bank Ids to be generated in the dropdown and the corresponding empName to be generated another field. So, I've used hashmap. In the struts html tag there is "list " attribute ..list key and list value. But Im nt very sure how the corresponding  empName is gona be printed in the below field

Comment: You are gonna print `empName` but it's not initialized. It won't be printed.

Comment: can you please explain..

Comment: It's unclear `I want the bank ids to be in the bank id column and the key values to be in the emp name column`. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: The bank Ids should be displayed in the dropdown @roman C . and the corresponding Names of the bank should be autofilled in the empName field. This is the expected output.

Comment: Please clarify what are bank ids and what are bank names? I didn't see the bank names in the code.

Comment: for your understanding i said bank names ..its emp  names actually.

Comment: <s:select label="Select Bank ID" 
        headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select bank id"  list="bankIds"  
        name="bankId" id="bankChange" />    

<s:textfield name="empName" label="Name" id="empName"></s:textfield>

Comment: these codes above in the jsp are the 2 fields involved. when I click on the dropdown comprises of the bank ids. The emp name should be auto filled

Comment: see the action class execute method. the map contains key value pair. i,e. bank ids and emp names pair

Comment: I can't see anything, could you please post an image.

Comment: :( its right there My first code is the action class and the second is the jsp of that.

Comment: do u knwo struts framework..?

Comment: Someone said I donknow it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814969/how-to-set-results-parameter-with-the-name-in-struts2#comment59400269_35814969

Answer (score 0):

The `bankIds` with corresponding `empName` are populated in the action method

```java
public String execute() throws Exception {
    bankIds = new HashMap<String,String>();
    bankIds.put("1541742","h6");
    bankIds.put("1541742","eft");
    bankIds.put("1394842","dfd");
    bankIds.put("1541742","dfee");

    //before returning to JSP you should set empName
    empName = bankIds.get(bankId);

    return "SUCCESS";
}
```

---

You didn't initialize `bankId` so it would be empty at the first time. After you submit the form the `bankId` will be populated and corresponding `empName` will be initialized. Both values will be pre-selected in Struts tags. Because you didn't use `value` attribute the value will be evaluated using `name` attribute.

You can use two action methods: one for rendering JSP using `GET` http method and another for submitting a form using `POST` http method. When `bankId` is posted the `bankIds` map should be already populated. So you should use another method `prepare()` to populate the map `bankIds`. To be called automatically before the action is executed and result JSP is returned the action class should implement `Preparable` interface.

```java
public class EmpLeavePlan extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {
    ...
    public void prepare() {
        bankIds = new HashMap<String,String>();
        bankIds.put("1541742","h6");
        bankIds.put("1541742","eft");
        bankIds.put("1394842","dfd");
        bankIds.put("1541742","dfee");
    }

    public String executeGet() throws Exception {

        //before returning to JSP you should set empName
        empName = bankIds.get(bankId);

        return "SUCCESS";
    }

    public String executePost() throws Exception {

        //before returning to JSP you should set empName
        empName = bankIds.get(bankId);

        return "SUCCESS";
    }
    ...
}
```

---

If you want to update `empName` when you select from the dropdown dynamically with javascript

```jsp
<s:select label="Select Bank ID" 
        headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select bank id"  list="bankIds"  
        name="bankId" id="bankChange" />    

<s:textfield name="empName" label="Name" id="empName" />
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#bankChange").change(function(){
    $("#empName").val($(this).val());
  });
});
</script>
```

---

Comment: Roman, thanks for the correction. I never came across the prepare method and executeget or executepost but just execute(). Can you kindly tell me how the struts.xml would look like.

Comment: <struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="aBankgen" class="com.action.EmpLeavePlan">
        <result name="SUCCESS">/index.jsp</result> </action>

        <action name="Bankgen" class="com.action.EmpLeavePlan"  method="display">
        <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result></action>

       <!--  <action name="BankDisplay" class="com.action.EmpLeavePlan"  method="dispBank">
        <result name="aa">/index.jsp</result></action> -->


    </package>
</struts>

Comment: the above is my current struts.xml

Comment: Don't post the code in comments, instead edit your question and add it there.